# How can I access flash (.swf) elements using capybara

Tags: capybara

Can I access `flash elements(.swf) using capybara`

Consider My web page having **text box, Check box, options and submit box within the flash content (.swf)** and I need to access those elements and I need to given an input and select the values and I need to submit the form.

Can I do this scenario using the capybara?

Any solutions please?

Comment: You can't do it with Capybara as AFAIK none of Capybara drivers supports Flash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aren't able to access the flash elements using Capybara.